# Number of rows in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? This code doesn't echo out anything. *I would like to see the number of rows* containing `$tag` in the `urlslug` field.

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE urlslug='$tag'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $num_rows;
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: This isn't looking for the number of rows where urlslug __contains__ $tag; it's looking for the number of rows where the exact value of the urlslug column __matches__ $tag exactly

Comment: You are mixed both `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `mysqli_query` function, but then you have the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_num_rows` function. Try [mysqli_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is not very efficient to select everything in a table, count it, and then throw it away again. You should use the MySQL `COUNT` function to count the rows:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(*) as numRows FROM tags WHERE urlslug='$tag'");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: The best answer imho.

Answer (score 1):

try this

> mysqli_num_rows($query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE urlslug='$tag'");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($mysqli,$query);
echo $num_rows;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

my ans with  @Sverri M. Olsen's ans  [Number of rows in a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334969/number-of-rows-in-a-mysql-table/23335043#23335043):

When you `COUNT(*)` it takes in count column indexes, so it will be the best result. Mysql with MyISAM engine actually stores row count, it doensn't count all rows each time you try to count all rows. (based on primary key's column)

If the `COUNT(*)` is slow, you should run `EXPLAIN` on the query, and check if indexes are really used, and where should they be added.

and +1 for @Sverri M. Olsen

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE urlslug='".$tag."'");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo $num_rows;
```